# I need to expedite datetime iterative function

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, optimization, iteration

I have some hourly data that I am processing in order to identify Time Lapses in the recorded data.  I've created a *time_break* array of timedelta values of zero hours whose values I am replacing with actual time breaks in the data as the for-loop finds them. This is taking almost 17seconds for 400k values...  I'd like to expedite this process..  Any ideas how?  thanks!

This is the way the column DATES looks like:

[image]

And my code:

```
delta_0h = timedelta(hours=0)
df_events['TimeBreak'] = delta_0h
time_break = df_events['TimeBreak'].to_numpy()
delta_1h = timedelta(hours=1)

def TimeLapse(df_events):
    numel = len(df_events)
    for r in range(1, numel):
        delta = df_events.loc[r, 'DATES'] - df_events.loc[r-1, 'DATES']
        if (delta > delta_1h):
            time_break[r] = delta
    return time_break

df_events['TimeBreak'] = TimeLapse(df_events)
```

I've tried converting DATES to a numpy array to optimize the function but I get an error saying that *Timestamp object is not subscriptable*.

I'd like to expedite this process..  Any ideas how?  thanks!

Comment: I don’t have my laptop with me to verify this, but you should be able to use np.diff(df_events[‘DATES’]) and it should give you the deltas.

Comment: @Ethan:  That did it.  thank you!  down to 2.6 secs.

Comment: Glad to help out 